# Why does center of mass in a lamina inverse the x and y in the notation?

Tags: calculus, notation

I have opened two textbooks and found the same notation in both. The notation for the center of mass in a lamina given by a variable density function $\rho(x,y)$ is $(\bar{x}, \bar{y}) = \left( \dfrac{M_y}{M}, \dfrac{M_x}{M}\right)$. This is where $$M =\iint_R \rho(x,y) dA$$ $$M_x =\iint_R y\rho(x,y) dA$$ $$M_y =\iint_R x\rho(x,y) dA$$

Why is the notation $M_x$ used when we are referring to the y-axis and vice versa?

Comment: See [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~conroy/m126-general/centerOfMass/centerOfMass01.pdf) for a different convention.

Comment: It uses the same convention that I'm describing. I'm not sure what is different.

Comment: It seems to me that it calls $M_x$ the moment with respect to the $x$-axis ...

Comment: Ah yes. However, the main component of my confusion remains : Why is $M_x$ used as the $y$ component of the COM such as $(\bar{x}, \bar{y}) = \left( \dfrac{M_y}{M}, \dfrac{M_x}{M}\right)$

Comment: Forget for a moment about the integral and consider a point-mass with mass $m$ located in the plane at point $(x,y)$. Its moment with respect to $x$-axis is $m \times y$, because the coordinate $y$ measure the distance of the point-mass from the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment about the $y$-axis depends on the distance from the $y$-axis.  The distance of a point $(x,y)$ from the $y$-axis is $x$.  The integral represented by $M_x$ has the $x$ because one integrates the function against $x$, which is, again, the distance from the $y$-axis.